# How to convert string to variable name to access value in json object?

Tags: jquery, json

How can I convert a string to a variable name that I can use to access a value in a json object?

This works, but "fname" is hard coded, not dynamic:

```
$("#ppl").append(people[i].fname);
```

I want something like this:

```
var myString = "fname";

$("#ppl").append(people[i].myString); // doesn't work
```

or

```
$("#ppl").append(people[i].window['myString']); // also doesn't work
```

Help!

Here is the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1zrsfe00/)

Comment: `people[i][myString]` should work?

Comment: you rock. worked! thanks.

Comment: Note: That's not JSON, that's a Javascript object. JSON is a text format to represent objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`people[i][myString]`

Will work.